# Maven multiple compiler arguments

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I am compiling a class using javac by passing argument **-XDignore.symbol.file**

Similarly I want to use the same in maven pom.xml.

```
<configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all -XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
```

The above configuration is not woking. Any ideas???

Comment: BTW: Which version of maven-compiler-plugin do you use?

Answer (score 4):

First you should use either [this:](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs)

```xml
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>-Xmaxerrs=1000</arg>
  <arg>-Xlint</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Or you can use the [following:](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArguments)

```xml
<compilerArguments>
  <Xmaxerrs>1000</Xmaxerrs>
  <Xlint/>
  <Xlint:-path/>
  <Averbose>true</Averbose>
</compilerArguments>
```

Furthermore why are you defining `<encoding>...</encoding>` manualy and not using the property:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

The above property will be picked up automatically by [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding)